# Slow insert and update in mongo using node.js as compared to Java

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb

I am writing stand alone script to insert some 5000 records in a collection. I am updating another collections using the same 5000 records.
My issue is when i write this using java with mongo it takes almost 1.1 second to run both operations one by one
But when i write it using Node.js it takes roughly 1.1 second to insert records and 10 seconds to update operation.

Both test Run were conducted on same collections with same indexes.
Could you please help me why Node.js is taking so much time almost 10 times than java

Node.js Version to update Records

```
   var db = new Db(articleDBName , new Server(mongoIP, mongoPort, {safe: false, strict: false}, {auto_reconnect: true}),{w:0});
db.open(function(error,db){
    var d = new Date();
    var tc = d.getTime();
    if(error){
        console.log(error);
        closeDB(db,dbName);
    }else{
        for(var i in logs){
            var record = logs[i];

                try{
                    var articleId = utils.getString(record["articleId"]);

                    var query        =  {"articleId":articleId} ;
                    var count        =  record["count"];

                    var author       = utils.getString(record["author"]);
                    var articleCount = db.collection("ArticleCountTempNode");                       
                    var updateObj = { $set:{"author" : author,
                        "channel" : channel
                    },$inc:{"count":count}};    
                    articleCount.update(query,updateObj,{upsert: true, multi:false},function(error, result) {

                        if(error){
                            console.log("Error Log " + error);
                        }else{
                        }
                    });

                }catch(error){
                    console.log("Error Log " + error);

                }


        }

        closeDB(db,articleDBName);
        var dt = new Date();
        console.log("time Taken Article Count----"+(dt.getTime() - tc));
    }
});
```

Java Version to update Records

```
    DB articleDBHistory = mongo.getDB(articleDBName);
    DBCollection articleCollHistory = articleDBHistory.getCollection(Config.ARTICLE_COUNT_COLLECTION);

    try {
        articleDBHistory.requestStart();

        DBObject query = null;
        BasicDBObject bDbObj = null;
        String articleId = null;
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (DBObject dbo : dbl)
        {

            articleId = dbo.get("articleId").toString();
            if (articleId != null && articleId != "") {
                query = new BasicDBObject("articleId",
                        dbo.get("articleId")));
                bDbObj = new BasicDBObject("$set",
                        new BasicDBObject("author", dbo.get("author")))
                        .append("$inc", new BasicDBObject("count",
                                ((Double)Double.parseDouble(dbo.get("count").toString())).longValue()));
                articleCollHistory.update(query, bDbObj, true, false);

            }
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        articleDBHistory.requestDone();
    }
```

Comment: Please show us both versions of the code.

Comment: You seem to have a nested for loop in the Node.js example, but not in the Java one. Are you sure these samples are equivalent?

Comment: #Hector Correa thanks for pointing that out it was unnecessary loop. I removed it but still time taken in node.js is almost 5 seconds as compared to java which takes 1 second

Comment: I don't understand how the node.js version is working as you seem to close the db connection before waiting for the all the `update` calls to complete.  You should also move your `db.collection` call outside of the loop.

Comment: Hi @JohnnyHK i m closing DB connection after the loop.

Comment: @viren Sure, but the loop is synchronous and the `update` calls are asynchronous so you're closing it too soon.

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks for pointing it out yes it can be a issue any time i think i need to put some logic here to close db connections once all update operations are done as i can not do it in callback of update  in loop